# Crontab job won't trigger or save

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

Trying to run my first crontab job (a python script) on Mac OS X El Capitan.

In the terminal I run: `crontab -e`
which opens a crontab.xyz123 file in Sublime Text (as I set it up). I put in the following cron syntax:

```
30 * * * * /Users/user.name/anaconda/bin/python /Users/user.name/Desktop/python_script.py
```

I just want it to run every half hour. The python script opens a youtube video and I've included it below:

```
#!/Users/user.name/anaconda/bin/python

print("this is a script")
```

When I run `crontab -l` I get the following error:

```
crontab: no crontab for user.name - using an empty one
crontab: no changes made to crontab
```

How can I get this to run properly? Is something wrong with the cron job? With the script?

Other note: I've changed the script permissions to be executable and I'm using only full paths in the crontab itself. What else could be wrong? I've run the script by itself in command line and it works fine.

Comment: Did you check the permissions of the python script?

Comment: You can't use relative paths in crontab. Please use the full path of the python script.

Comment: Use shebang is incorrect. #!/Users/user.name/anaconda/bin/python would be the right one. Did you trying running the python script outside of the crontab?

Comment: @LokeshA.R. You *can* use relative paths in `crontab`.  The cron job runs in the invoking user's home directory; with this in mind, you can specify relative paths just fine.